# Generate box shapes on click, if there is no empty space left disable button

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to make a game where with a click of a button I generate random boxes. If there is no space left for another box, the button should be disabled.

CodeSandbox link: [codesandbox.io/s/still-wind-w0dygo](https://codesandbox.io/s/still-wind-w0dygo?file=/src/App.js)
Thanks!